# Video will not stay on 2nd column of row bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a video that is in a row. I want it to stay to the right of the page as a 2nd column of the row. But it keeps appearing under the first column as if it is a second row.

here's my code:

```
<section class="container-fluid aboutus">
  <div classs="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Read more</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 video">
        <div>
            <video autoplay muted loop width="550">
            <source src="video/Markcard.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
        </video> 
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue: change `<div classs="row">` to `<div class="row">`
Second issue: `col-sm-*` will only work with small devices you are going to want to handle other devices as well. In the example below I simply used `col-*`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container-fluid aboutus">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <h1>Our Mission</h1> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. </p>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Read more</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-7 video">
        <div>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xcJtL7QggTI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </video> 
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize I had misspelled class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish that would be with the CSS Flex-Box layout. Here is a link to a tutorial in case you don't know where to start.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp